# Making NSUserDefault of type Integer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a NSUserDefault variable that stores integer values here is my code right now.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(0, forKey: "HighScore")
```

When I input a number as an original value, it identifies it as UInt8 not just an Int. How do I change this?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "someKey")` how about this? Alternatively you can do this: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(0), forKey: "someKey")`

Comment: Wow, im straight up dumb... I even knew .setInteger existed... I have no idea what I was thinking haha Thanks for helping me and my stupidity

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Swift 3:**

You could just use the `set(Int, forKey: String)` method Swift provides:

```
//Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourInt, forKey: "intKey")
//Get
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "intKey")
```

---

**Swift 2:**

You could just use the [`setIntegerForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey:)-method Swift provides:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//Set
defaults.setInteger(yourInt, forKey: "intKey")
//Get
defaults.integerForKey("intKey")
```

Comment: Ok mr. Best Answer. `defaults.integerForKey(...)` returns `Int`. What if I need to get `Int?`? In other words how to differ the situation when you didn't set any value yet?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov in that case you need to use the `.object(forKey:_)` method and cast it to an `Int?` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in the very latest version of Swift 3 you don't have to indicate data type. Just write:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(DataType, forKey:"DATAKEY")
```

Example:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(5, forKey:"MY_INTEGER")
UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey:"MY_STRING")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"MY_BOOLEAN")
```

See this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) for more information and on how to retrieve the stored data type.

Answer (score 1):

```
setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey: String)
```

As you can see, the value you provide is of type AnyObject?. Simply wrap your value in Int()

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(0), forKey: "HighScore")
```