# How to change the type of a value from UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I'm trying to compare a value that was saved to UserDefaults to a new integer but I cant figure it out.

```
func setScore() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let newScore = score
    if defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore") != nil {
        defaults.set(newScore, forKey: "HighScore")
        let highScore = defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore") as! Int
        print(highScore)
    } else if defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore") < Int(newScore) {
        defaults.set(newScore, forKey: "HighScore")
        let highScore = defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore") as! Int
        print(highScore)
    } else {

    }
}
```

How can I change the value from `defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore")` to be an integer so I can compare them?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UserDefaults`? There are methods for reading specific types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930736/making-nsuserdefault-of-type-integer-in-swift

Comment: Note that you only get to the `else if...` clause if `defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore")` is nil, so your comparison doesn't make much sense anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use `UserDefaults.standar.integer(forKey:)` to retrieve a value of type `Int`. Secondly, you should store the casted value once and shouldn't retrieve it several times (currently you retrieve it 3 times instead of just 1).

Moreover, your logic is flawed. You are trying to compare the value if the retrieved value was `nil`. So you are not just trying to compare `Any?` to `Int`, you are trying to compare `nil` to `Int`.

```
func setScore() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let newScore = score
    if let highScore = defaults.object(forKey: "HighScore") as? Int {
        print(highScore)
        if highScore < Int(newScore) {
            defaults.set(newScore, forKey: "HighScore")
        }
    }
}
```

The same function, but retrieving the `Int` value straight away without having to cast (`UserDefaults.integer(forKey:)` returns 0 if there is no value stored for that key).

```
func setScore() {
    let newScore = score
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "HighScore") < Int(newScore) {
            defaults.set(newScore, forKey: "HighScore")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I assumed that I needed the nil statement but I didn't. Works perfectly now.